# CSS styling a link within a div class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to stop a link from turning purple when you click it. My link is within a div with the class name "header". My code doesn't seem to work and the link just stays purple.

```
.header a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the html? Without it we have 50% of information.

Comment: Something might be overriding it, you need to post the full code

Comment: Your CSS code look right! I'm curious about your HTML code?

Comment: I realised that in my HTML i had given the div a class but also each link its own class

Answer (score 1):

The :visited selector is used to select visited links. If your HTML looks the same as below it should be working, Possibly you might want to use :focus or :active?

```
.header a:visited {
    color: black;
}

.header a:focus {
    color: pink;
}
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">sdfsd</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="https://codepen.io/">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ctrl + shift + r`, might just be a browser cache thing.